# Efficient sum of products

Tags: numpy, loops, optimization

I am looking to write the following sum of products:

[image: Equation of sums of products]

in the most efficient way in Python.

Note that `f(j,i)` and `g(k, i)` are just some functions of the indices, usually fractions of the form  `j^c_1/i^c_2`. Furthermore, when  `i ==j`, then the first product would have to evaluate to `1`. I have though of a Kronecker delta as a workaround to this but every suggestion is welcome on how to impose such conditions.

The issue is that I would require the "limit" behaviour of this and thus, I would like to iterate for a large number of `n`. I have not written products before, mostly sums and I was wondering how to go ahead with this. I am more or less familiar with loops but I have read there are also other, more efficient ways of accomplishing this, e.g. iterators.

What is the best way to do this and could you please provide a working example?
My attempt so far is very basic, as I am aware of the structure of the sum/product but not how to evaluate it.
Here is what I have so far:

```
product_1 = 1
product_2 = 1
for i in range(a, n + 1, 1):
    for j in range(a, n + 1, 1):
        if i == j 
            something to make the product 1
        else:
            product_1 *= f(i,j)
    for k in range(b, n + 1, 1):
        product_2 *= g(i,k)
```

Then  somehow times the products and have a summation variable somewhere?

Comment: What attempt?  I don't see any attempt here.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thanks for your comment. My question does not state anywhere: "Here is my attempt" or anything close to that. I was hesitant to include it as it is quite basic. Should I do so?

Comment: You should *always* include your attempt; it makes it easier to tell what you are having difficulty with.

Comment: @ScottHunter Thank you, you are right. I have done so, but I am quite confident it is far from complete. As you can I am not sure how to times the products and then take their sum.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way to code this would be:

```
result = 0
for i in range(a, n + 1, 1):
    product_1 = 1
    product_2 = 1
    for j in range(a, n + 1, 1):
        if i != j:
            product_1 *= f(i,j)
    for k in range(b, n + 1, 1):
        product_2 *= g(i,k)
    result += product_1 * product_2
```

To time your code, I suggest you check [this page](https://realpython.com/python-timer/#a-python-timer-decorator) which is a great introduction to timing in Python.

To evaluate this faster, check the `map` operator or, if you want to work with NumPy, the [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) function that you could use to vectorized both `f` and `g` in this context. You could also vectorized the outer loop.